# Is it possible to use mouse buttons as toggles?

Tags: hardware, mouse, input-devices

An application I use requires me to hold LMB pressed for very long time. This may be uncomfortable. Is there any way, to get mouse button stay pressed event though I have released? A toggle-like behavior would be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I know of any tools that does exactly that, but you can use xdotool mousedown  and xdotool mouseup . So I suppose you'd want a script that sets mousedown or up when run, and then run that script by pressing another mouse button or something.